# AWS Instance: ping not reaching

Tags: amazon-web-services

I created a micro-instance for some testing, and set it up. I installed Docker, and ran simple Nginx image.

Now from the host, when I do

```
> curl localhost
```

It works. But when I try to access the same with my given public IP, it does not work. (returns with Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT on Chrome).

Could this be because I changed the hostname from `ip-172-31-X-X` to something else?

I also ran `nmap -sT -O localhost` to verify that port 80 is open:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00030s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
80/tcp open  http
...
```

But ping is not working, neither am I able to access the index page via public IP. What's going on?

Reference:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Security_Guide/s1-server-ports.html

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

1. Change the security group to allow port 80 inbound traffic
2. Do NOT change the `/etc/hostname` to anything else. Keep it what it was initially. If you have to change it, follow this:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html